# Crear un array vacio reactivo

Tags: typescript, vue3

Estoy tratando de generar un array vacio en mi script setup de vue 3, pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo al querer definirlo reactivo.

Las cosas que intente fueron las siguientes:

```
<script setup lang="ts">

import { ref } from 'vue'

interface gs {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    ....
}
```

esto:

```
const layout: gridsystemobject[] = ref<gridsystemobject[]>([]);
const layout: gridsystemobject[] = ref([]);
```

da este error:

> "message": "Type 'Ref<{ x?: number | undefined; y?: number |
> undefined; w: number; h: number; i: number; }[]>' is missing the
> following properties from type 'gridsystemobject[]': length, pop,
> push, concat, and 31 more.",

esto:

```
const layout = ref([]);
```

no da error en la definicion, pero si da error al querer hacer un push al array.

> Property 'push' does not exist on type 'Ref<never[]>'.

```
const layout = ref<gridsystemobject[]>([]);
```

> Property 'push' does not exist on type 'Ref<{ x?: number | undefined;
> y?: number | undefined; w: number; h: number; i: number; }[]>'.

Obviamente algo falla en toda la definicion, pero no logro identificar como quiere que lo expecifique.

Aclaro que si saco el ref, todo funciona, salvo que no es reactivo, que obviamente hace que no sirva para nada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acuerdo con [esta entrada](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html) en la documentación de Vue, la función `ref` devuelve un tipo `Ref` que es una interfaz genérica declarada de la siguiente forma:

```
interface Ref<T>
{
  value: T
}
```

Como se aprecia, este tipo presenta una propiedad `value` que alberga la referencia al tipo genérico envuelto.

---

Entendido esto, simplificamos el hecho de saber el porqué de los errores que obtienes.

Primero, esto:

```
const layout: gridsystemobject[] = ref<gridsystemobject[]>([]);
const layout: gridsystemobject[] = ref([]);
```

Equivaldría a algo como esto:

<sup>Soy consciente de que `Ref` es una interfaz, pero esto es tan solo un ejemplo.</sup>

```
const layout: gridsystemobject[] = new Ref<gridsystemobject[]>([]);
const layout: gridsystemobject[] = new Ref([]);
```

Donde se intenta convertir un tipo `Ref` en un tipo `Array` de forma implícita. `Ref` no puede convertirse a `Array` y tampoco posee las propiedades y funciones del tipo `Array`, lo que desencadena en este error:

> "message": "Type 'Ref<{ x?: number | undefined; y?: number | undefined; w: number; h: number; i: number; }[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'gridsystemobject[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 31 more.",

---

JavaScript es un lenguaje de tipado dinámico, inclusive con TypeScript adjunto, donde puedes o no especificar el tipo de una variable o función y, en caso de no hacerlo:

```
const layout = ref<gridsystemobject[]>([]);
const layout = ref([]);
```

No obtienes error alguno en la definición porque `layout` asume automáticamente esta forma:

```
const layout: Ref<gridsystemobject[]> = ref<gridsystemobject[]>([]);
const layout: Ref<[]>                 = ref([]);
```

Pero, intentar llamar a `push`, `pop`, `shift`, `slice`, `length` o cualquier otra propiedad del tipo `Array` en `layout` siempre desencadenará en este error:

> Property 'push' (or 'pop', 'shift', etc.) does not exist on type 'Ref<{ x?: number | undefined; y?: number | undefined; w: number; h: number; i: number; }[]>'.

Porque el tipo `Ref` contiene únicamente la propiedad `value` y es esta la que expone el tipo envuelto, en este caso `gridsystemobject[]`.

---

Dicho lo anterior, te propongo llamar a `value` para hacer `push` a tu arreglo reactivo.

Declara tu variable `layout` de alguna de estas formas:

```
const layout = ref<gridsystemobject[]>([]);
const layout = ref([]);

const layout: Ref<gridsystemobject[]>  = ref<gridsystemobject[]>([]);
const layout: Ref<[]>                  = ref([]);
```

Y entonces, cuando desees operar sobre su valor, en este caso el arreglo, llamas a `value`:

```
layout.value.push(...)
```